# Unable to install vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git and vala-panel-appmenu-common-git in Manjaro

Tags: xfce, manjaro, aur

I wanted to install vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git and vala-panel-appmenu-common-git in Manjaro. So I first used:
`pamac build vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git` in the terminal.
This is the output I got:

```
Preparing...
Cloning vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git build files...
Generating vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git information...
Checking vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git dependencies...
Resolving dependencies...
Checking inter-conflicts...

To build (2):
  vala-panel-appmenu-common-git  0.7.6.r13.gb5e9b0a-1    AUR
  vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git    0.7.6.r13.gb5e9b0a-1    AUR


Edit build files : [e] 
Apply transaction ? [e/y/N] y


Building vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git...
==> Making package: vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git 0.7.6.r13.gb5e9b0a-1 (Thursday 20 January 2022 07:23:39 PM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Updating vala-panel-appmenu git repo...
Fetching origin
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    vala-panel-appmenu ... Skipped
==> Removing existing $srcdir/ directory...
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Creating working copy of vala-panel-appmenu git repo...
Cloning into 'vala-panel-appmenu'...
done.
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
The Meson build system
Version: 0.60.3
Source dir: /var/tmp/pamac-build-anujtambe/vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git/src/vala-panel-appmenu
Build dir: /var/tmp/pamac-build-anujtambe/vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git/src/build
Build type: native build
Project name: vala-panel-appmenu
Project version: 0.7.6
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 11.1.0 "cc (GCC) 11.1.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.36.1
Vala compiler for the host machine: valac (valac 0.54.5)
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.8.0)
Run-time dependency gio-unix-2.0 found: YES 2.70.2
Run-time dependency gdk-pixbuf-2.0 found: YES 2.42.6
Run-time dependency gtk+-3.0 found: YES 3.24.31
Run-time dependency libbamf3 found: YES 0.5.5
Run-time dependency libwnck-3.0 found: YES 40.0
Run-time dependency vala-panel found: YES 0.4.92
Run-time dependency libmatepanelapplet-4.0 found: YES 1.26.1
Run-time dependency libxfce4panel-2.0 found: YES 4.16.3
Run-time dependency libxfconf-0 found: YES 4.16.0
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.22.1)
WARNING: CMake Toolchain: Failed to determine CMake compilers state
Run-time dependency budgie-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

vala-panel-appmenu/meson.build:81:0: ERROR: Dependency "budgie-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

A full log can be found at /var/tmp/pamac-build-anujtambe/vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git/src/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

And then i ran: pamac build vala-panel-appmenu-common-git
This is what I got:

```
Preparing...
Checking vala-panel-appmenu-common-git dependencies...
Resolving dependencies...
Checking inter-conflicts...

To build (1):
  vala-panel-appmenu-common-git  0.7.4-1    AUR


Edit build files : [e] 
Apply transaction ? [e/y/N] y


Building vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git...
==> Making package: vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git 0.7.6.r13.gb5e9b0a-1 (Thursday 20 January 2022 07:25:16 PM)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Updating vala-panel-appmenu git repo...
Fetching origin
==> Validating source files with sha256sums...
    vala-panel-appmenu ... Skipped
==> Removing existing $srcdir/ directory...
==> Extracting sources...
  -> Creating working copy of vala-panel-appmenu git repo...
Cloning into 'vala-panel-appmenu'...
done.
==> Starting pkgver()...
==> Removing existing $pkgdir/ directory...
==> Starting build()...
The Meson build system
Version: 0.60.3
Source dir: /var/tmp/pamac-build-anujtambe/vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git/src/vala-panel-appmenu
Build dir: /var/tmp/pamac-build-anujtambe/vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git/src/build
Build type: native build
Project name: vala-panel-appmenu
Project version: 0.7.6
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 11.1.0 "cc (GCC) 11.1.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc ld.bfd 2.36.1
Vala compiler for the host machine: valac (valac 0.54.5)
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /usr/bin/pkg-config (1.8.0)
Run-time dependency gio-unix-2.0 found: YES 2.70.2
Run-time dependency gdk-pixbuf-2.0 found: YES 2.42.6
Run-time dependency gtk+-3.0 found: YES 3.24.31
Run-time dependency libbamf3 found: YES 0.5.5
Run-time dependency libwnck-3.0 found: YES 40.0
Run-time dependency vala-panel found: YES 0.4.92
Run-time dependency libmatepanelapplet-4.0 found: YES 1.26.1
Run-time dependency libxfce4panel-2.0 found: YES 4.16.3
Run-time dependency libxfconf-0 found: YES 4.16.0
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.22.1)
WARNING: CMake Toolchain: Failed to determine CMake compilers state
Run-time dependency budgie-1.0 found: NO (tried pkgconfig and cmake)

vala-panel-appmenu/meson.build:81:0: ERROR: Dependency "budgie-1.0" not found, tried pkgconfig and cmake

A full log can be found at /var/tmp/pamac-build-anujtambe/vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git/src/build/meson-logs/meson-log.txt
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

And When I wrote the names of both packages at the same time like in pacman that is:

```
pamac build vala-panel-appmenu-common-git vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git
```

It just told me this:

```
Preparing...
Checking vala-panel-appmenu-common-git dependencies...
Error: Failed to prepare transaction: target not found: vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git



Edit build files : [e] 
Apply transaction ? [e/y/N] ^C
```

It didn't find vala-panel-appmenu-xfce-git.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in vanilla arch. Installing `gobject-introspection` package (available in official repo) took care of it.